# Why Tor cant access localhost pages

Tags: python, proxy, socks, tor

I have Tor running and a python script to get web pages:

```
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

print urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()
```

However, if the URL is

```
http://localhost/some_page.html
```

I get the following error:

```
raise Socks5Error(ord(resp[1]),_generalerrors[ord(resp[1])])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Can someone explain to me what exactly happens?

Thank you.

Comment: My guess would be that it goes through loopback interface, rather than via normal ways. Try using your real interface's IP address, rather than 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Doesn't work that way either..

Comment: so any web request you are trying to make, other than localhost, returns that error meaning you cannot route your traffic over Tor?

Answer (score 16):

It is the way protocol is designed. When you send a request, it is transported to another machine on Internet with Socks5 envelope. So actual request is made from external server, thus accessing 127.0.0.1 is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tor proxy with php in localhost. Using cURL. Put your local IP on LAN  proxy config "No proxy for:". Exammple 192.168.1.10. Then call your php as "http://192.168.1.10/your_script.php"

```
$proxy = '127.0.0.1:9150';
$ur = "http://anydomain.com";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ur);

    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
```