# How to access Django's development server using Tor Browser?

Tags: python, django, tor

I already installed and created a Django project. Then I run the command `python manage.py runserver`, which gives me:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 14 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

April 19, 2018 - 16:28:03
Django version 2.0.4, using settings 'personal.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

All is well, and if I access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` on Mozilla Firefox, I get the initial 'Congratulations!' page with the rocket taking off. If I access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` on Tor Browser, however, I get an 'Unable to connect' error. I can access other websites normally.

What's the problem here, and how can I access my development server using Tor Browser instead of Mozilla Firefox?

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/11994/how-to-access-local-host-through-tor-browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Tor cant access localhost pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060096/why-tor-cant-access-localhost-pages)