# How can I open jupyter notebooks in tor browser

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to create a twitter plugin but due to restrictions from my ISP, social media is inaccessible leaving me with the option to use tor browser to access social media including twitter. However, much as I am able to open my notebooks in chrome and safari, they are not opening in my tor browser. This is the error I get
Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:8889.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Tor Browser is permitted to access the Web.
```

Has anyone faced this before? Anyone with a hint on how to overcome this will be of great help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Tor cant access localhost pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060096/why-tor-cant-access-localhost-pages)

Comment: It makes sense now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for using Jupyter notebook with Firefox browser installed on xenial, including initial installation of jupyter notebook using pip2:

```
sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4
pip2 install virtualenv
virtualenv jupyter
source jupyter/bin/activate
pip2 install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

This solution was tested on:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial.
```

It was run on 32bit Chromenotebook

Jupyter notebook will be open automatically. However, everytime loging in on Jupiter again, at first source needs to be activated:

```
source jupyter/bin/activate
```

and then:

```
jupyter notebook
```

to start.

[image: Firefox and terminal screens]